# Finding memory location in running application

Tags: linux, memory

In old good DOS 5.0 times I was using some resident program for finding (and modifying) memory location of program variable. Typically lives, or ammunition in games (yea cheating). It was taking memory snapshot to disk and making diffs.  One can also narrow the search using using greater, smaller comparison. Then it was able to fix the value and so on.

If it's possible, how can I do something similar in current Linux(64bit)? Is there such a tool? I was trying radare2 for tracking the calls, but the binary is stripped and I'm getting lost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The memory of a Linux process can be examined and modified by mapping pieces of the `/proc/<PID>/maps` pseudo file. You can discover where the different parts of the process are by reading `/proc/<PID>/maps` and other similar files.

The problem you'll face is that many things have changed since the old good DOS times. In those times, with just a few tens of kilobytes for your program, global variables were the norm, and those are easy to find.

But now, with hundreds of megabytes, most programs will use dynamic memory, complex hierarchies of classes, virtual functions... and that will make your cheats a lot harder.

Comment: You are probably right that the complexity grow to much for this simple approach. I tried dumping the memory using `gcore` and comparing the generated 75MB files. This helped me to narrow the search to ~1600bytes which is still to much..

Answer (score 0):

Also the pmap command will show you the memory locations (starting points and size) used by the process.

For example, if I had a process with id 123:

```
pmap 123
```